# disabling sorting in CrossTab of Crystal Report

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, crosstab

I have report with Crystal Report and there is a Cross Tab inside of it. In order to pass data to CrossTab I create a DataTable , do some processing on the data and pass it to Crosstab In Report, In Cross Tal I have 3 Group By's. I dont want the cross tab changes the sorting of data I have pass them to it.

This is by default happens in cross Tab Group by
[image]

But I dont want the value be sorted.

any Idea for that?

Comment: What happens if you check `Use a Formula as Group Sort Order` and create a Formula which always returns `1`? Does the sorting still change?

Comment: @MatSnow: the columns are sorted by ascending

Comment: Do you want to disable the default sorting?

Comment: @Siva: I don't want the CrossTab does the sorting

Comment: Default sorting is applied when you develop a report, If you don't want to get sorted then you need to change once cross tab is designed

Comment: @Siva: how can I do it in design time? do you have any example?

Comment: See the options in dropdown of the window you posted in question there you have few options if not you click option below use formula as group sort expert

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to maintain the order that the values are loaded into the report, the quickest way is probably to alter the SQL yourself.

[image]

Create a new returning field in your SQL statement that starts at 1 and increments with each record. Then tell the Crosstab to sort on the field you just made.

Comment: I couldn't see your picture, do you have a sample?